# Python : Updating multiple words in a text file based on text in another text file using in_place module

Tags: python-3.x, replace, in-place

I have a text file say storyfile.txt
Content in storyfile.txt is as

> 'Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
>      Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
>    All mimsy were the borogoves,
>       And the mome raths outgrabe

I have another file- hashfile.txt that contains some words separated by comma(,)

Content of hashfile.txt is:

> All,mimsy,were,the,borogoves,raths,outgrabe

### My objective

My objective is to 
 1. Read hashfile.txt

 2. Insert Hashtag on each of the comma separated word

 3. Read storyfile.txt . Search for same words as in hashtag.txt and add hashtag on these words.

 4. Update storyfile.txt with words that are hash-tagged

### My Python code so far

```
import in_place

hashfile = open('hashfile.txt', 'w+')
n1 = hashfile.read().rstrip('\n')
print(n1)

checkWords = n1.split(',')
print(checkWords)

repWords = ["#"+i for i in checkWords]
print(repWords)
hashfile.close()

with in_place.InPlace('storyfile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        for check, rep in zip(checkWords, repWords):
            line = line.replace(check, rep)
            file.write(line)
```

## The  output

can be seen here
https://dpaste.de/Yp35

Why is this kind of output is coming?
Why the last sentence has no newlines in it?
Where I am wrong?

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAFN4.png)

attached image

## The current working code for single text

```
import in_place

with in_place.InPlace('somefile.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.replace('mome', 'testZ')
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: What's the point of `storyfile = open('storyfile.txt', 'r+')`?  You don't do anything with `storyfile`, and having two filehandles open for `storyfile.txt` may be what's messing with `in_place`.

Comment: yes, it is true.I have edited it. But still result is not what was expected

Comment: following @Srce Cde , I have removed one indent from last line.
file.write(line) And its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look if this helps. This fulfills the objective that you mentioned, though I have not used the in_place module.

```
hash_list = []
with open("hashfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        for j in i.split(","):
            hash_list.append(j.strip())
with open("storyfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        for j in hash_list:
            i = i.replace(j, "#"+j)
        print(i)
```

Let me know if you require further clarification on the same.